# IOS-9 disable right to left in hebrew / arbic

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Please advice how to change all the app programatically to right to left. 
from iOS 9 apple set the hebrew / arbic region as left to right (mirroring).

Please advice if there is any option to change this ?

Regards Yakir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the interface language to English. Currently it is the only way (unless apple will get convinced it was a bad idea)

**Edit**:
If you want your app to behave "English only" - you can force the locale in the code:
In `AppDelegate` add to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        if (![[languages firstObject] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}
```

Comment: I think only now I understood you question, edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Boaz - It might be better and safer to place this code in the **main.m** file instead of in the `didFinishLaunching` method.
(don't have enough Rep. to add this as a comment the the original answer)

And... You don't need to get the array of languages/check the first language, you can simply set it to be "en":

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(OS_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"9.0"))
{
    if(RightToLeftLanguage)
    {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
}
```

"[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];" this statement enforce the view to be rendered in right to left mode without considering your app or device language.
Make sure call this statement in viewDidLoad.